# ionic / android - blue bar appears on top

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developping an app using ionic framework.

The app uses the camera to take pictures.

Everything functions perfectly in android for a few days on my samsung phone until sundunly, after a few days, a blue bar appears on top when launching the app (instead of a black bar normaly, see the print screen attached).As a consequence, the camera does not function anymore for instance.
[image]
This does not happen for other beta tester using other phone brands as Wiko for instance. It only happens with samsung phone (two cases so far).

Reseting the phone to the factory original settings doesn't change anything.

So the important part is that **if I change the android "package id" of the app, then everything functions well again...** until the bar comes back again a few days later... (without changing the code, i.e. with the same exact build...)

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide that blue status bar ,you can use these set of code in your ionicPlatform.ready function

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    return StatusBar.hide();
  }
});
```

Also make sure you have cordova statusbar plugin installed for this to work. If you don't have it, Add it.

It was hard to determine from your question what you exactly looking for.But I hope this helps you. Thanks